# difference between IO-APIC-fasteoi and IO-APIC-edge

Tags: interrupt

In /proc/interrupts, I can see that some interrupt numbers belong to IO-APIC-fasteoi and some belong to IO-APIC-edge.

What is the difference between the two types of interrupt controllers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference lies in the way the interrupts are triggered. The -edge interrupt are edge triggered. This is a rising level on the interrupt line.
The -fasteoi interrupts are level interrupts that are triggered until the interrupt event is acknowledged in the programmable interrupt controller (PIC). The EOI stands for End Of Interrupt. See also [Wikipedia article on EOI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_interrupt).